# dynamic div sizing on one page only?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-transitions

[Live site.](http://urbanpalate.com/portfolio/)

My site is set up so that an image or gallery is displayed over a wooden background(`#above`), with the rest of the content below on a linen background(`#below`). This works well on every page but the portfolio page- the wooden space has no content until a specific gallery is selected.

Is there a way to have the linen background & content(`#below`) show instead of the plain wooden background(`#above`), until the gallery has been selected? (And if so, is it possible to have it appear to be sliding down from the top of the screen?)

header.php

```
<body>
<div class="above">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Urban Palate logo" id="logo" /></a>
        </div><!-- end logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?page_id=7"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="Urban Palate intro" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=12"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio.png" alt="Urban Palate portfolio" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=15"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog.png" alt="Urban Palate blog" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="?page_id=10"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact.png" alt="Urban Palate contact" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- end header -->
```

portfolio.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>  

    <div class="gallery">
       <?php     
            if( is_page( 24 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider1]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 26 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider2]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 28 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider3]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 30 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider4]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 32 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider5]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 34 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider6]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 36 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider7]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

        <?php     
            if( is_page( 42 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider8]');
            } else {
              // output standard content here
            }

        ?>

    </div><!-- end gallery -->
</div><!-- end above -->
<div class="below">
    <div class="blurb">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio_blurb.png" alt="see who has experienced our fabulous + creative and beautiful + cutting edge decor firsthand" />
    </div><!-- end blurb -->
    <div id="client-list">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- end client-list -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of improvements that could be made to the code above. Investigate the `switch` statement, or at least ditch all the `else` blocks. Anyway,

In your `header.php`, try

```
<body>
<div class="above <?php if (is_page(1)) echo 'short'; ?>">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
        // etc...
```

You will need to change the `is_page(1)` part to have the correct page number. I don't know how you figure this out with WordPress, but if you can do it for each gallery, you can do it for the empty portfolio page.

Then, in your site css:

```
.above.short {
    height: 200px;
}
```

My solution is ugly, but it will fit in with the rest of the PHP you've got there. If you paid developers for that work, get new developers.

Somebody who knows WP may be able to tell you how to give `div.above` an additional class without resorting to inline code like I've done. This would be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks to be exactly what I need.
As for the code, as I'm sure you can tell, this is my first time attempting something like this and is the result of a lot of Q&A's here and reading various articles.
By ditching the `else`, could I simply have:

`<?php     
            if( is_page( 24 ) ) {
              // make your stuff here
               echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider slider1]');
            } 
        ?>`

Comment: Spot on :) I don't have a Wordpress install to test it on, but I think the code at this link could replace your whole `<div class="gallery"> ... </div>` block: http://pastebin.com/2GpyciGW. Sorry for being rude about the code. There is no excuse for insulting someone trying to learn.

Comment: A little constructive criticism never hurt anyone :)
And thank you for the additional help; that code looks TONS better.

Comment: No worries. I also noticed that your images, css and javascript  files don't have cache headers set. This would let browsers use cached copies of all those assets. Instead they have to download them on every page view. Here in Australia that means a 4-6 second page load time. You could start reading about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching. Finally, the "about-above-img.png" picture is half a megabyte. I'd recommend JPEG compression for photographic content - you could reduce that by 80% with no noticable quality loss.

Comment: I've just turned on WP Super Cache plugin- that should take care of the caching, right?

Comment: Caching PHP files and caching static content (css, js, images, etc) are slightly different jobs. You're doing the former via Super Cache, but SC needs to cooperate with the webserver to get the latter working. Make sure steps 7, 8 and 9 from http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/installation/ are all good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery.

For example:

```
// check if the gallery is empty and hide if it is.
if ($('.above .gallery').contents().length == 0){
  $('.above').hide();
}
```

or use css instead of `.hide` and `display:none` or set the height to 0.

```
 $('.above').css('height', '0');
```